# Single/double quote bug in sass/stylesheet Webpack loader?

Tags: sass, webpack

I've run into an issue with a chain of webpack loaders for scss files, where sometimes using single quotes for a string (legal in Sass, as I understant) causes a compile fail. I have an example that can be run, here, based on small changes from the AngularClass angular starter app:

https://github.com/karptonite/angular2-webpack-starter

You can see the relevant Webpack [rule here](https://github.com/karptonite/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js#L104-L111).

This [commit](https://github.com/karptonite/angular2-webpack-starter/commit/e03f44c5297bf1c320c9aed4468fffd6e0c9fbbb) shows the only changes from the vanilla starter from AngularClass necessary to reproduce the bug. Instructions to reproduce the compile failure are in the README of the repo.

I'd like to report this as a bug, but I'm having trouble determining which loader to blame.  possible culprits include sass-loader, resolve-url-loader, css-loader, and the ExtractTextPlugin.

I know for a fact that the error does not occur when I remove the resolve-url-loader, but it also doesn't seem to occur when I don't use the ExtractTextPlugin.

I spent hours tracking down why the build wasn't working before discovering it was the single/double quote issue; I'd like to save other people that time by reporting it to the correct repo, if I can figure out what package is at fault, but I don't know enough about how these loaders work to track it down.  Can someone who understands Webpack and/or Sass take a look at this, and tell me if I've found a legitimate bug, and, if so, which loader should be fixing it?